# Count number of occurences in different dataframes, and get the line numbers as strings

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, group-by, sumifs

`Report$keyid = c(ab~2000~to81~~91,cb~1000~tr50~xz~23~45,yo~1999~~es~21~45)
key_id = c(cb~1000~tr50~xz~23~45, ab~2000~to81~~91, cb~1000~tr50~xz~23~45, yo~1999~~es~21~45)
desc = c(low, medium,low, high)
error=data.frame(key_id, desc)`

Report dataframe consists of all unique values, whereas Error has duplicate values too.

I want to add a column Report$errorcount such that I get the number of occurrences for each Report$keyid comparing it with Error$key_id in the error dataframe.

Another column Report$errorline such that it tells the positions wherever the keyids occur in the error dataframe. The actual dataframe contains thousands of rows.

Desired Result -

```
Report$errorcount = c(1,2,1)
Report$errorline = c("2","1,3","4")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working, but you might want to check if the errorline column produced in the code below gives you exactly what you want.

```
library(dplyr)

key_id = c("cb~1000~tr50~xz~23~45", "ab~2000~to81~~91", "cb~1000~tr50~xz~23~45", "yo~1999~~es~21~45")
desc = c("low", "medium","low", "high")
error = data.frame(key_id, desc)
error$errorline <- row_number(error$key_id)

Report <- data.frame(
  keyid = c("ab~2000~to81~~91","cb~1000~tr50~xz~23~45","yo~1999~~es~21~4")
)

tb <- as.data.frame(table(error$key_id))
colnames(tb) <- c("keyid", "errorcount")

Report <- left_join(Report, tb) 
Report <- left_join(Report, error, by = c("keyid" = "key_id"))
Report <- Report[-3] # drop desc column
```